# Как добавить каждому пользователю новое значение Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

Есть 2000 пользователей нужно добавить каждому новое значение language: ru
Пример кода:

```
[{
"id": 0,
"name": "Ivan",
"surname": "Ivanov",
"coins": 10,
"money": 0
},
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Sergey",
"surname": "Dmitrievich",
"coins": 15,
"money": 5
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Nikolay",
"surname": "Alekeevich",
"coins": 13,
"money": 1
}]
```

Должно получиться:

```
[{
"id": 0,
"name": "Ivan",
"surname": "Ivanov",
"coins": 10,
"money": 0,
"language": ru
},
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Sergey",
"surname": "Dmitrievich",
"coins": 15,
"money": 5,
"language": ru
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Nikolay",
"surname": "Alekeevich",
"coins": 13,
"money": 1,
"language": ru
}]
```

Comment: `UserModel.updateMany({}, {language : 'ru'))`

Comment: @Yaant не работает :_

Comment: А поле `language` в модели-то описано?

Comment: @Yaant в схеме да

Comment: Разве updateMany не обновляет уже существующие поля в БД?

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен насколько этот способ безопасен но должен работать.

```
//Получаем данные, добавляем свойство и сохраняем в БД.
const data = await Model.findOne({yourFilter})
data.language = "ru"
await data.save()
```

Соответственно если документов много то перебираем их и добавляем свойство.